# Pass mouseover event to another using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Consider the HTML below

```
<span id='one'>one</span>
<span id='two'>two</span>
```

and CSS

```
span {
  background-color:green;
  display: inline;
  color: white;
}

span:hover {
  background-color:red;
}
```

What I want is: when mouse hover `two`, the `one` will also be hovered, so I use the jQuery

```
$('#two').hover(function (e) {
    var p = $(this).prev().trigger(e.type);
});
```

Seems not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/59rnyj6f/

Comment: That's a JavaScript event handler not a CSS hover handler.

Comment: Check following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/59rnyj6f/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a class to one, let's say "pseudo-hover", and when #two is hovered/unhovered toggle the "pseudo-hover" class on #one?

```
#one.pseudo-hover { background-color:red; }

$('#two').hover(function (e) {
    $("#one").addClass("pseudo-hover");
}, function (e) {
    $("#one").removeClass("pseudo-hover");
})
```